# How to access backwards directories from localhost?

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I have WAMP pointing at the folder `site`.
I want to access the folder `cms` from the browser address bar, but I don't know how to since I'm trying to access a backwards directory.

Here's what my directory looks like:

```
main: -> public -> site
      -> private -> cms

// Server pointing at site
// main has 2 folders: public & private
```

Also, when I deploy the legitimate website, how will I access the `cms` folder?   Will I have to create a subdomain in order to do this, or is there another way?

Comment: It is not totaly clear what your directory structure is from the question. Please try again

Comment: Sorry, I edited it take a look now

Comment: Do you know what absolute paths are? It is generally a good idea to use them. These are absolute paths: `/public/site/myimage.png` and `/private/cms/beauty.css`. Relative paths are relative to your current position on the site. So, if you are on `public/file.txt` then `../private/anotherFile.txt` would move you over to the private folder (go back one folder, then into another folder).

Comment: I understand the difference now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access directories outside of your localhost tree. If your webserver is at 192.168.0.1 and you set site folder to be hosted under that address you cannot point your browser/webapp to access what's outside of that folder on higher level (e.g. the folder public, private, main or cms). That would be a serious security issue if that would be possible.

If I understand correctly you host folder site at your localhost and you want to access ../private/cms.

Comment: Yes I do. If I can't access the cms folder where it is now, then where would be the most secure place to access it? Should I put it in public?

Comment: You should be hosting the "main" folder then. You would access site with 192.168.0.1/public/site and once there you can use ../private/cms to access private content (actually I think it would be ../../private/cms in your case if "site" is also a folder) or 192.168.0.1/private/cms to access it directly. Obviously anyone else will be able to do the same, therefore you should protect yourself, for example by restricting the access to private folders. You can also use subdomains for simplier addresses if that concerns you.

Comment: I see. Are those IP addresses some random ones that you're using as an example? Also, where can I look into this further?

Comment: Yes, these are random addresses used as an example, they will be your web server's IP. What further information do you need? There is no more information regarding the case, you just cannot browse server's local files using web browser.